Pixel sensitivity in a convolution operation
So a Gaussian blur convolution looks like this:
formula for Gaussian Blur
Now, it seems rather common to take the partial derivatives with respect to a change in x or y. And in CNNs you get the partial derivatives with respect to weights.
But what I want is the partial derivative of the output pixel with respect to the input pixel.
Basically the sensitivity of the output pixels with respect to a change in the input pixel. This would give a jacobian matrix I believe. But I am unsure of how to calculate each element.

I don’t see x and y in your formula above, do you mean u and v?

err yes, thanks for that clarification. U and V.

But what I would want is H(i,j) points to a specific point.
I would want the sensitivity of this point wrt the input point

https://hannibunny.github.io/orbook/preprocessing/04gaussianDerivatives.html
see this lecture.
But unlike the derivatives they find here, I would like the sensitivity of the output pixels to a change in the input pixels

If we take i and j to be continuous variables, then it would indeed give the Jacobian, and in that case, $J_H=J_F$. Not sure how you could interpret that in your case, but i guess you could use finite differences in each of your variables to compute the partial derivatives.
